# Spring Boot mocking other rest clients when testing

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot

I'm consuming a remote api in my Spring MVC project using RestTemplate. One client is for authentication named `LoginApiClient` and I have to use this in all other rest clients.

This one my rest client that uses `LoginApiClient` and consumes QrCode Api.

```
@Service
public class QrKeyApiClient implements QrKeyApiClientBase {

  private RestTemplate restTemplate;

  @Autowired
  private LoginApiClientBase loginApiClient;

  public QrKeyApiClient(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    restTemplate = builder.build();
    restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler());
  }

  //Other implementation details
}
```

And this is `LoginApiClient`

```
@Service
public class LoginApiClient implements LoginApiClientBase {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public LoginApiClient(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        restTemplate = builder.build();
        restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler());
    }

    //Other implementation details
}
```

My unit test class for `QrKeyApiClient` is like below.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@RestClientTest({QrKeyApiClient.class})
@Category(IUnitTest.class)
public class QrKeyApiClientTest {

  @Value("${getQrCodeUrl}")
  private String getQrCodeUrl;

  @Mock
  LoginApiClient loginApiClient;

  @Autowired
  private MockRestServiceServer server;

  @InjectMocks
  private QrKeyApiClient client;

  @Test
  public void getQrCodeAsImage_makesTrueCallToApi() throws Exception {
    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = mock(ResponseEntity.class);
    HttpEntity requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(qrCodeGenerateRequest,new HttpHeaders());

    this.server
        .expect(requestTo(this.getQrCodeUrl))
        .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.POST))
        .andRespond(withSuccess("successResult", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));

    String qrImage = this.client.getQrCodeAsImage(qrCodeGenerateRequest);

    server.verify();

    assertThat(qrImage, is(notNullValue(String.class)));
  }
}
```

I'm not sure this is the right way to do this but I want to mock my `LoginApiClient` in this test and inject it to `QrKeyApiClient`. But my test not passes with an error that says *"Error creating bean with name 'qrKeyApiClient': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'loginApiClient';"*

So how I can test this client with mock of other clients that member of it.

Comment: Can you try to use `@MockBean` instead of `@Mock` and remove the `@InjectMocks`? These are Mockito annotations. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html

Comment: With `@MockBean` annotation my `LoginApiClient` can mocked truely. But after removing `@InjectMocks` there is a problem with `QrKeyApiClient`. I added `@Autowired` to `QrKeyApiClient` and problem solved. Thanks for your answer  @FrontierPsychiatrist

Comment: No problem! Maybe add the solution as an answer and mark it as solved!

Comment: I am a  new user and not have 15 reputation to do this :) You can answer and I mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem is a mixed usage of Spring and Mockito annotations. Spring provides the `@MockBean` annotation to mock services in the application context.

Try replacing `@Mock` with `@MockBean` and `@InjectMocks` with `@Autowired`. The `requestEntity` and `responseEntity` are not needed then probably.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@RestClientTest({QrKeyApiClient.class})
@Category(IUnitTest.class)
public class QrKeyApiClientTest {

  @Value("${getQrCodeUrl}")
  private String getQrCodeUrl;

  @MockBean
  LoginApiClient loginApiClient;

  @Autowired
  private MockRestServiceServer server;

  @Autowired
  private QrKeyApiClient client;

  @Test
  public void getQrCodeAsImage_makesTrueCallToApi() throws Exception {    
    this.server
        .expect(requestTo(this.getQrCodeUrl))
        .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.POST))
        .andRespond(withSuccess("successResult", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));

    String qrImage = this.client.getQrCodeAsImage(qrCodeGenerateRequest);

    server.verify();

    assertThat(qrImage, is(notNullValue(String.class)));
  }
}
```